# AWS Amplify 503 error when using Next.js getStaticProps revalidate

Tags: next.js, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

I have tried to use Nextjs getStaticProps function on a page

and deployed it on AWS Amplify. However when I gave the option 'revalidate'

AWS cloudfront occurred an error. A 503 error saying it didn't have permission

something like that... does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Was an awesome question, I think. vote you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, go in Cloudwatch logs in the region where the error occurred, with Log Insights, find the error. You will get more details about the reason Lambda raised a 503.

I bet it's SQS rights.
As quoted here:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/2175#issuecomment-900514998

Fixable like this:

TL;DR: Add SQS rights to your lambda function execution role.

1/ With your log error, you will get the lambda function name
[image]

2/ Go to the lambda function configuration, and get Role name, then click to edit
[image]

3/ Edit the permission policiy in JSON and add this:

```json
       {
            "Action": [
                "sqs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:*:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
```

Review and apply, it should work.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful for me. Thank you. Hope everyone vote you.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the "revalidate" from 60 to 600 did the trick for me.